# java print pdf with printdialog

Tags: java, pdf, printdialog

How can I print a pdf showing the printDialog?

Now I am printig with this code:

```
public static void print2(){
     InputStream is = null;    
      try
      { 
         PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
         DocPrintJob printerJob = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();

         File pdfFile = new File(TEMPPDF);
         is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pdfFile));
         Doc simpleDoc =  new SimpleDoc(is, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
         printerJob.print(simpleDoc, null);


      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
      }
}
```

But I would show the print dialog:

```
public static void print2(){
     InputStream is = null;    
      try
      { 

         PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
         //pj set pdf file to print ...?         
         pj.printDialog();

      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
      }
}
```

Comment: You need a PDF library.